# Looking for small, lightweight tracking device

Tags: gps, tracking-devices

I am looking for a tracking device that actively transmits and uses GPS or mobile networks for tracking, as well as transmitting the information to an application.

- The more miniscule or lightweight, the better, unless it puts battery life below a reasonable use threshold (say, a few days).
- Spatial resolution is good but not essential.
- Ideally the price of the service should not be too high, and the price of the device needs to be reasonable enough to buy a few of them (i.e. under 200 USD).

Answer (score 2):

1. Make your own using Raspberry Pi with GSM module, battery and additional software to track it.  This is the hard way.
2. "Car" trackers can be actually used for other purposes. [This $199 device](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N1F9OV7) looks good
   but there's also a way [cheaper alternatives](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07W5VVGQJ) that costs only $24.95

3. Two Phones method. Basically all you need to do is just to turn on GPS on the phone #1, place it somewhere and track it using #2 phone "Track my Phone app". (depends on device)